# Difference between boundedElastic() vs parallel() scheduler

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, scheduler

I'm new to Project reactor and trying to understand difference between `boundedElastic()` vs `parallel()` scheduler. [Documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/) says that `boundedElastic()` is used for blocking tasks and `parallel()` for non-blocking tasks.

Why do Project reactor need to address blocking scenario as they are non-blocking in nature. Can someone please help me out with some real world use case for `boundedElastic()` vs `parallel()` scheduler
?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66681652/355438

Comment: boundElastic() enables to run a blocking IO operation to run in a separate thread. Because there are still some certain libraries which may already be there which are blocking and you still have to integrate them in your Reactor project. Including them without this will block the Reactive stream pipeline

Answer (score 11):

### TL;DR

Reactor executes non-blocking/async tasks on a small number of threads. In case task is blocking - thread would be blocked and all other tasks would be waiting for it.

- `parallel` should be used for fast non-blocking operation (default option)
- `boundedElastic` should be used to "offload" blocking tasks

In general Reactor API is concurrency-agnostic that use `Schedulers` abstraction to execute tasks. `Schedulers` have responsibilities very similar to `ExecutorService`.

### `Schedulers.parallel()`

Should be a default option and used for fast non-blocking operation on a small number of threads. By default, number of threads is equal to number of CPU cores. It could be controlled by `reactor.schedulers.defaultPoolSize` system property.

### `Schedulers.boundedElastic()`

Used to execute longer operations (blocking tasks) as a part of the reactive flow. It will use thread pool with a default number of threads number of CPU cores x 10 (could be controlled by `reactor.schedulers.defaultBoundedElasticSize`) and default queue size of 100000 per thread (`reactor.schedulers.defaultBoundedElasticSize`).

`subscribeOn` or `publishOn` could be used to change the scheduler.

The following code shows how to wrap blocking operation

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    // blocking operation
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()); // run on a separate scheduler because code is blocking
```

`Schedulers.newBoundedElastic()`
Similar to `Schedulers.boundedElastic()` but is useful when you need to create a separate thread pool for some operation.

Sometimes it's not obvious what code is blocking. One very useful tool while testing reactive code is [BlockHound](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound)

Answer (score 4):

The parallel flavor is backed by N workers (according to the N cpus) each based on a ScheduledExecutorService. If you submit N long lived tasks to it, no more work can be executed, hence the affinity for short-lived tasks.

The elastic flavor is also backed by workers based on ScheduledExecutorService, except it creates these workers on demand and pools them.
BoundedElastic is same as elastic, difference is that you can limit the total no. of threads.

https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/13/flight-of-the-flux-3-hopping-threads-and-schedulers

Answer (score 1):

Schedulers provides various Scheduler flavors usable by publishOn or subscribeOn :
1)parallel(): Optimized for fast Runnable non-blocking executions
2)single(): Optimized for low-latency Runnable one-off executions
3)elastic(): Optimized for longer executions, an alternative for blocking tasks where the number of active tasks (and threads) can grow indefinitely
4)boundedElastic(): Optimized for longer executions, an alternative for
fromExecutorService(ExecutorService) to create new instances around Executors

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html