# In a Flux<Flux<T>>, how to complete the outer Flux if the inner Flux<T> is eventually empty

Tags: java, project-reactor

Consider the following code under these condition:

> `getOneResponePage(int)` produces a `Flux<Integer>`.
> It's simulating a request to fetch a page of results from another service.
> It's implementation should be can be treated as black box for my questions.
> (See below for an explanation of it's actual purpose.)
>
> `getOneResponePage(int)` will eventually return an empty `Flux<Integer>`, which is it's way to signal that no more results will come.
> (But it will keep on emiting empty `Flux<Integer>`.)

```java
package ch.cimnine.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public class PaginationTest {
    @Test
    public void main() {
        final Flux<Integer> finalFlux = getAllResponses();

        finalFlux.subscribe(resultItem -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200); // Simulate heavy processing
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            }

            System.out.println(resultItem);
        });
    }

    private Flux<Integer> getAllResponses() {
        Flux<Flux<Integer>> myFlux = Flux.generate(
            () -> 0, // inital page
            (page, sink) -> {
                var innerFlux = getOneResponePage(page); // eventually returns a Flux.empty()

                // my way to check whether the `innerFlux` is now empty
                innerFlux.hasElements().subscribe(
                    hasElements -> {
                        if (hasElements) {
                            System.out.println("hasElements=true");
                            sink.next(innerFlux);
                            return;
                        }

                        System.out.println("hasElements=false");
                        sink.complete();
                    }
                );

                return page + 1;
            }
        );

        return Flux.concat(myFlux);
    }

    private Flux<Integer> getOneResponePage(int page) {
        System.out.println("Request for page " + page);
        
        // there's only content on the first 3 pages
        if (page < 3) {
            return Flux
                .just(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23, 27, 31)
                .map(i -> (1000 * page) + i);
        }

        return Flux.empty();
    }
}
```

### Goal

The goal is to have one method that is called `getAllResponses()` which returns a continuous `Flux<T>` of results.
The caller should not know – or care – that some pagination logic happens internally.
All other methods will be hidden from the caller.

### Questions

1. Since I'm new to reactive programming, am I thinking this right?
2. IntelliJ warns me that *Calling 'subscribe' in non-blocking context is not recommended*. How to do it right?

### What's `getOneResponePage(int)` actually?

In my actual code, `getOneResponsePage(int)` is sending a request using `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient`.
It connects to a service that is returning results.
The service only returns a max of 1000 results per call.
An `offset` parameter must be sent to get more results.

The API is a bit weird in the sense that the only way to know for sure whether you have all the results is to query it repeatedly with an ever-increasing `offset` until you get an empty result set.
It will happily return more empty result sets for a still-increasing `offset` (… until some internal maximum for `offset` is reached and a `400 Bad Request` is returned.)

The actual implementation of `getOneResponePage(int)` is almost identical to this:

```java
private Flux<ResponseItem> getOneResponePage(int page) {
    return webClientInstance
        .get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> {
            uriBuilder.queryParam("offset", page * LIMIT);
            uriBuilder.queryParam("limit", LIMIT);
            // …
        })
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(ResponseItem.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to avoid `Flux<Flux<T>>`. Another anti-pattern is to subscribe explicitly (`innerFlux.hasElements().subscribe`). Ideally you need to subscribe only once, typically on framework layer (e.g. WebFlux subscribes in the underlining HTTP server).

Querying data with a continuously increasing pointer (page number, offset, etc) is a very common pattern and you could use `expand` operator to implement it. In case of `Flux` it will try to expand every element. For pagination usually `Mono<List<T>>` is more useful. Expand will try to expand every page and will stop when `getOneResponePage` returns `Mono.empty()`.

```
private Flux<Integer> getAllResponses() {
    var page = new AtomicInteger(0); // initial page
    return getOneResponePage(page.get())
            .expand(list -> getOneResponePage(page.incrementAndGet()))
            .flatMapIterable(Function.identity());
}


private Mono<List<Integer>> getOneResponePage(int page) {
        System.out.println("Request for page " + page);

        // there's only content on the first 3 pages
        if (page < 3) {
            return Flux
                    .just(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23, 27, 31)
                    .map(i -> (1000 * page) + i)
                    .collectList();
        }

        return Mono.empty();
    }
```

2. In case your flow is non-blocking you need to subscribe on `parallel` scheduler. `boundedElastic` should be used to "offload" blocking tasks. Use `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())`. For more details you could check [Difference between boundedElastic() vs parallel() scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61304762/difference-between-boundedelastic-vs-parallel-scheduler)

Comment: With your example, when does it end increasing the page? Or in other terms, how will the Flux that is returned from `getAllResponses()` complete? It's because `getOneResponsePage` will just return an empty collection up to page Integer.MAX or even Long.max, but that are many unnecessary calls to the remote service.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that it was `Flux`. In this case it will try to expand every element. For pagination better to use `Mono<List<T>> ` and then flatten it using `flatMapIterable`. Let me update the example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of stopping the outer flow from the inner flow. The closest thing would be to use `switchIfEmpty` with a `Flux.error(NoSuchElementException)` in on the inner sequence, then on the outer sequence use `onErrorResumeNext` and return an empty `Flux` if it finds that `NoSuchElementException`.

```java
Flux.just(listOf(1, 2, 3), listOf(), listOf(4, 5, 6))
.flatMap(list ->
     Flux.fromIterable(list)
     .switchIfEmpty(Flux.error(new NoSuchElementException()))
)
.onErrorResumeNext(e -> 
      e instanceof NoSuchElementException ?
      Flux.empty() : Flux.error(e)
);
```